# How to wrap a object in a lambda in Android API <24

Tags: java, android, java-8, functional-programming

I want to iterate a collection acting over every item.

```
Collection<Listener> listeners = ....

interface Listener {

    void onEventReceived();

    void onShutDown();
}
```

The code could be:

```
void notifyShutdown() {
    for(Listener listener:listeners){
        listener.onShutDown();
    }
}
```

I want to seize the java8 lambdas so I declared a helper interface:

```
interface WrapHelper<T> {
    void performAction(T item);
}
```

and a notify method

```
public void notifyListeners(WrapHelper<Listener> listenerAction) {
    for (Listener listener : listeners) {
        listenerAction.performAction(listener);
    }
}
```

So I can declare methods like:

```
public void notifyEventReceived() {
    notifyListeners(listener -> listener.onEventReceived());
}

public void notifyShutDown() {
    notifyListeners(listener -> listener.onShutDown());
}
```

My question is: Do I need to declare the interface `WrapHelper` myself of there is an already existing class for this purpose in Android API <24.

Comment: I don't know about Android API, but have you got access to JDK8's `java.util.function.Consumer`? This is what would correspond to your `WrapHelper`.

Comment: There's a bunch of options, e.g. [java-support](https://github.com/ipcjs/java-support), [LWS](https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API), [android-retrostreams](https://github.com/retrostreams/android-retrostreams). Just to name a few.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you need to declare your interface WrapHelper since API<24 does not support Consumer from java.util

Altough, you can use [Lighweight-Stream-API library](https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API) wich provides ready-to-use classes and interfaces like Supplier, Consumer and Optional. It works almost the same as Java8 new features and works fine in API < 24 .